# Safari overflow-y: scroll vs overflow-y: hidden issue. scroll adding extra blank space beneath divs

Tags: html, css, safari, frontend

First off, thanks in advance for the help!

I'm having an issue with safari and `overflow-y: scroll;` adding a bunch of blank space per div. However `overflow-y: hidden;`  does not add the extra space, but obviously my divs are not scollable with overflow hidden.  This is only a problem with Safari, all other browsers are behaving as expected.  Any help is greatly appreciated, ran out of ideas on how to get Safari to behave.

with `overflow-y: scroll;`
[image]

with `overflow-y: hidden;`
[image]

Comment: Oh also, this isn't an iOS issue, tried adding `webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` as I saw in a few posts with similar issues, did not help.

Answer (score 0):

all i actually needed was `vertical-align: top;`.  if anyone ends up with the same issue with Safari, go with that vertical-align.